# Running a Java application in the background of a linux server

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I want to run jwebsocket server on my server.
I don't have Tomcat installed and I would prefer avoiding it if possible (though it is not that essential to me).
jwebsocket is a .jar application. What I do now to run it, is log in to my server via SSH, and start it. However in that way it turns the entire SSH console to it's own log, and if I want to disconnect from the SSH, I must close it first.

Is there a way to just run it in the background?

If this is not the recommended way, I would prefer to just install Tomcat. But since Tomcat is unnecessary to me besides for one specific application, I would prefer to avoid it if it is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run it with

```
java -jar yourapp.jar > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Can you explain what does the '> /dev/null &' does?

Comment: > /dev/null does output to nowhere (silent mode), & releases the shell, so you can continiue using it

Comment: OK, thanks. just 2 more questions if I may. How can I send the output to a log file? And in case I've released the shell, how do I orderly shut the application down? I can of course just use 'top' to kill it, but that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: to make an output to log file just use '> /var/log/yourapp.log &' or elsewhere. To execute any remote command (including shutdown) you may implement some listener, and pass pass commands to it with client app. Another option is to kill the process.